# SignalR Request.Url throws exception

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I'm using SignalR in my asp.net application.
I've noticed that in times the url object is returned empty and throws an exception when trying to access it.

Here's an example of an error message that was caught a couple of days ago.
Can't I assume the Url object will be populated? What may be causing it?

[image: SingalR url exception]

Comment: Is the Context.Request null or just the Context.Request.Url? (FYI: Please use code instead of screenshot)

Comment: Context.Request is not null, and Context.Request.Url is not null either it just show an exception when viewing it in the watch

Comment: Is this in hub class ?